# Updating parallel array when one array is sorted which has repeated element

Tags: java, c++, sorting

I have two array. `Array1=[5,4,3,3,2]`. `Array2=[2,7,1,2,5]`.

I want to use these two arrays parallely. Like when elements of `Array2` changes order then `Array1` elements changes order accordingly. So for my program I sorted Array2 and it becomes `Array2=[1,2,2,5,7]`. So Array1 must be changed to `Array1=[3,3,5,2,4]`.

I want to know how to do this(psudocode or java or c++). I have provided the code I tried in C++ below. *The problem is it does not work when an element duplicates.* So after it sorts `Array2` to `[1,2,2,5,7]` it updates `Array1` to `[3,5,5,2,4]` ( you should understand why it is giving this output by looking at the code below).

So my task is when `Array2` is updated(elemnts changes order) so should `Array1`. It has to work when `Array2` has duplicate elements.

```
  k=0;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    int a=arr1[i];
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(a==arr2[j])
        {
            arr4[k]=arr1[j];
            k++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to include the code sample you keep referring to.

Comment: It has been added. Thanks

Comment: Java and C++ are two different languages.  Please pick just one.

Comment: Thats right. I want any code sample in Java or C++. Any of 1 will be fine by me.

Comment: I am suggesting a different solution, please discard if you don’t want to use. Design a class with two fields, one for the number from array1 and one for the number from array 2. Instead of the two int arrays, make one array of objects from this class. Now no matter how the array is reordered, the numbers from each of the original arrays will always follow each other. Also, it’s easy to sort by either the first or the second number as necessary.

Comment: I have not understood properly. Can you show me some code sample ?

Comment: @NazmusSalehin Why is it two separate arrays of `int` instead of just one array, something like `struct data { int x; int y;};`?  Then create an array of `data`.  And if you want to keep two arrays, then the better way to go is to have a third array of indices and sort those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the arrays must be parallel, the better way to sort them is to have a third array of indices, and sort those integers based on Array2.  Note this is C++ code, not Java:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::array<int, 5> Array1 = {{5,4,3,3,2}};
   std::array<int, 5> Array2 = {{2,7,1,2,5}}; 
   std::array<int, 5> indices = {{0,1,2,3,4}};

   // only sort the indices, based on Array2
   std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [&](int n1, int n2)
              { return Array2[n1] < Array2[n2]; });

   // output results
   for (auto& i : indices)
      std::cout << Array1[i] << " ";
   std::cout << "\n";
   for (auto& i : indices)
      std::cout << Array2[i] << " ";
}

Output:
3 5 3 2 4 
1 2 2 5 7
```

The output function could have also been written this way:

```
   // output results
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      std::cout << Array1[indices[i]] << " ";
   std::cout << "\n";
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      std::cout << Array2[indices[i]] << " ";
```

Comment: I understand.Thank you very much :)

Comment: btw what is the function of the 3rd parameter in the sort function ?

Comment: It is a lambda function.  It returns `true` if the first item should come before the second item, `false` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks . And forgive me as i am not used to advanced usage of C++ and have another question. How this & is working in the 3rd parameter. And also in for each loop you have also used auto&. What is its function ?

Comment: The `&` is a lambda capture.  The `for` loop is a range based for loop.  Java has them also.  The point is that you can do all of this without `std::sort`, but you must be aware of what was done rather than the syntax.  You could implement a Java solution similar to this, where you just need a third array of indices, and sort the indices based on the values in Array2.  I just edited the answer to show what those loops are actually doing.

Comment: @NazmusSalehin -- Basically, the arrays stay the same, no items are moved.  The only thing adjusted is the index array.  I don't know the Java syntax too well, but the other solution by OleVV seems to be changing Array2 and Array1, and this C++ solution does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting a different solution, please discard if you don’t want to use. Design a class with two fields, one for the number from array1 and one for the number from array 2. Instead of the two int arrays, make one array of objects from this class. Now no matter how the array is reordered, the numbers from each of the original arrays will always follow each other. Also, it’s easy to sort by either the first or the second number as necessary.

I didn’t expect to write the code for you, but on your request here are some useful snippets in Java to get you started. The class is quite simple, two fields, constructor and getters:

```
public class ParallelNumbers {

    /** number from array 1 */
    int elem1;
    /** number from array 2 */
    int elem2;

    public ParallelNumbers(int elem1, int elem2) {
        this.elem1 = elem1;
        this.elem2 = elem2;
    }

    public int getElem1() {
        return elem1;
    }

    public int getElem2() {
        return elem2;
    }
}
```

You may of course add `toString` method and what else you may like. Since you know your domain better, you can also find a better name for the class. With this class you may do:

```
    ParallelNumbers[] all = new ParallelNumbers[] { new ParallelNumbers(5, 2), new ParallelNumbers(4, 7),
                    new ParallelNumbers(3, 1), new ParallelNumbers(3, 2), new ParallelNumbers(2, 5) };
    System.out.println("Numbers from array 1: " 
            + Arrays.stream(all).map(ParallelNumbers::getElem1).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    System.out.println("Numbers from array 2: " 
            + Arrays.stream(all).map(ParallelNumbers::getElem2).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

You will recognize your original arrays in the printout:

```
Numbers from array 1: [5, 4, 3, 3, 2]
Numbers from array 2: [2, 7, 1, 2, 5]
```

As an example of sorting, here’s how to sort the `ParallelNumbers` elements first by `elem2`, next by `elem1` (to resolve clashes):

```
    Arrays.sort(all, 
            Comparator.comparingInt(ParallelNumbers::getElem2).thenComparingInt(ParallelNumbers::getElem1));
    System.out.println("Numbers from array 1: " 
            + Arrays.stream(all).map(ParallelNumbers::getElem1).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    System.out.println("Numbers from array 2: " 
            + Arrays.stream(all).map(ParallelNumbers::getElem2).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

This time it prints:

```
Numbers from array 1: [3, 3, 5, 2, 4]
Numbers from array 2: [1, 2, 2, 5, 7]
```

Exactly as you had requested, isn’t it?

EDIT: Something similar has been written before. See for example [Anti-pattern: parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/) and [Parallel array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array).

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot about taking advantage of Comparator. :)

Comment: @Ole V.V -- I will upvote if you give a Java solution similar to the C++ solution I had.  It seems you're adjusting the source arrays (correct me if I'm wrong).  If so, then a more optimal solution in terms of execution time is to have an index array, and just sort the index array based on Array2.  Don't know Java that well to add to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulMcKenzie, for your comment and sportsmanly offer. We have already written plenty of code for this downvoted question, and people are ready to downvote you and me too if we turn SO into a code writing service. (continued in next comments)

Comment: The point is I consider the design with two parallel arrays a poor one. The reasons for that view is explained in the two articles I link to in the bottom of my answer. So you are correct, I replaced the two int arrays with one object array. On purpose.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, what makes you think you need better performance than my code offers? And what makes you think you will get better performance if I redesign to match yours?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, for comparison I liked your suggestion `struct data { int x; int y;};` and an array of `data` better (my solution resembles this one more).